# Galois closure uniqueness confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm a little bit confused by the statement of this corollary, (Corollary 23 pg 594 of Dummit and Foote)

Let $E/F$ be any finite separable extension. Then $E$ is contained in an extension $K$ which is Galois over $F$ and is minimal in the sense that in a fixed algebraic closure of $K$ any other Galois extension of $F$ containing $E$ contains $K$.

What does he mean exactly by saying "in a fixed algebraic closure of $K$..."?

Comment: The algebraic closure is only unique up to isomorphism. If $E$ is an extension of $F$, then the algebraic closure of $E$ is "the same" as the algebraic closure of $F$ since $F$ is embedded in $E$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I get it now, thanks.